# How to add a node in an XQuery transform?

Tags: marklogic

I'm writing a transform to use with a call to /v1/search. In my transform, I just want to add an element to the contents. I think I'm getting caught up by the fact that the incoming content is in JSON, but for some reason I've decided to write this function in XQuery.

A simple transform function of:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace mymodule = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/mymodule";
declare function mymodule:transform(
  $context as map:map,
  $params as map:map,
  $content as document-node()
  ) as document-node()
{
  let $new-node := <foo>bar</foo>
  [...]
  return $content
}
```

When I do `xdmp:describe` on the incoming `$content` it looks like:

```
document{object-node{"snippet-format":text{"mysnippet"}, "total":number-node{1}, 
"start":number-node{1}, "page-length":number-node{10}, "selected":text{"include"}, 
"results":array-node{object-node{"index":number-node{1}, "uri":text{"/path/to/file.txt"}}}}}
```

How do I go about adding `$new-node` to `$content`? Or if `$content` is immutable, creating a new document node that contains both?

Comment: You can't just add an XML node to a JSON document. Do you want to add a JSON property with the XML serialized as a text value? If so, what would you want to call that property? Or do you instead want to create a "foo" property with the value "bar"?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to mutate and return the results without altering the document in the database, then you need to first convert it from a database node into a plain old JSON object that can be manipulated. You can use '[xdmp:from-json()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json)' for that.

```
let $updated-content := xdmp:from-json($content)
```

Then, you can treat it like a `map` use the [`map:put()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/map:put) function to add a property with your desired value. Assuming you wanted to make the property the name of the foo element: `$new-node/name()`.

Then, you need to decide what value to use for that property. If you put an XML element as the value, it will auto-magically serialize that element to a string and put as "bar". You can do that explicitly with `xdmp:quote()`.

```
let $updated-content := xdmp:from-json($content)
let $_ := map:put($updated-content, $new-node/name(), $new-node) 
return $updated-content
```

If you simply wanted to have a property called "foo" and a value of "bar", driven from whatever the containing element name and value was:

```
let $updated-content := xdmp:from-json($content)
let $_ := map:put($updated-content, $new-node/name(), $new-node/data())
return $updated-content
```